# In-App Review API how to get callback when user rated app

Tags: android

I have implemented google In-App Review API and launched from onCreate method

```
private void inAppReviewDialog(Context context) {

    ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(context);

    Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
    request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // We can get the ReviewInfo object
            ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();
            Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow((Activity) context, reviewInfo);
            flow.addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
                // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
                // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
                Log.v(this.getClass().getName(),"In Dialog Success");
            });

        }else {
            Log.v(this.getClass().getName(),"In Dialog failed");
        }
    });


}
```

Is there any way i can get callback that user rated successfully ?

Comment: No. As per the docs, the developer doesn't get any information whatsoever. Look at the last code snippet comment here : https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java